# Access Mule global variable from a custom transformer

Tags: java, mule

How can i access a Mule global variable from my custom transformer? 
I have a variable (in a properties file), called blaze.services.address - which is definitely being loaded (i use it in MEL). My code:

```
import org.mule.api.MuleContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.context.MuleContextAware;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import com.vatit.blaze.esb.exception.HttpResponseException;

public class HttpErrorResponseChecker extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

    @Override
    public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
        Integer statusCode = Integer.parseInt((String)message.getProperty("http.status", PropertyScope.INBOUND));
        String payload;
            try {
                payload = message.getPayloadAsString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
                payload = "Unknown payload";
            }


        muleContext.getRegistry().get("blaze.services.address");
        if (statusCode >= HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
            throw new HttpResponseException(this, statusCode, "Exception caused by call to HTTP service", payload);

        return message.getPayload();
    }

}
```

**problems**:

setMuleContext never stops on a breakpoint (never called?)
`muleContext.getRegistry().get("blaze.services.address")` returns null

Anyone have an idea?

**EDIT (transformer config):**

In response to David's comment I have removed duplicate implementation of MuleContextAware, however the result remains the same.

My transformer config looks like this:

```
<custom-transformer class="com.vatit.blaze.esb.transformer.HttpErrorResponseChecker" name="HttpErrorResponseChecker" doc:name="Java">
    <spring:property name="blazeServicesAddress" value="${blaze.services.address}"/>
</custom-transformer>
```

Which works (_blazeServicesAddress property not shown in java code), but i'd prefer to access the property directly, not have to inject.

**EDIT 2 (property placeholders):**
This is the way our properties files are loaded:

```
<spring:beans>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:blazedefault.properties" order="0"/>
    <context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:blazeoverride.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" ignore-unresolvable="true" order="-1"/>
</spring:beans>
```

Comment: How do you configure this transformer in Mule XML?

Comment: `context:property-placeholder` supports multiple locations so you do not need two of them, just use `location="classpath:blazedefault.properties,classpath:blazeoverride.properties"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AbstractMessageTransformer` already implements `MuleContextAware`, as you can see here: https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transformer/AbstractMessageTransformer.html

So you can remove support for it from your custom transformer and just use the `muleContext` protected field that comes from here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/bfb3a17263d1e4b32ee10272cbf710a2bf41b16b/core/src/main/java/org/mule/transformer/AbstractTransformer.java#L58

**EDIT**: In fact, the correct way to do what you want to achieve is to Spring-inject `blaze.services.address` into `HttpErrorResponseChecker` from the Mule XML configuration, instead of looking it up programmatically like that.

Comment: Hi David, my bad for not checking existing MuleContextAware implementation - I've now cleaned up my code (see edit). However, `muleContext.getRegistry().get("blaze.services.address")` still returns null. Regardless of other potential solutions, I'd like to know how to access the property file props from a transformer.

Comment: Properties are not exposed like that in Spring, you can't even read them straight from the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean. You need to load them in a `Properties` bean, via `util:properties` then inject it in the `context:property-placeholder-resolver` (so Spring can resolve `${}` props) and then you can access the `Properties` bean from the Mule registry, and read values in it.

Comment: I believe we are doing that (see **Edit 2**), and these properties are available with `${}`. Is there another step we're missing? Pls excuse any ignorance - new to Java as well as Mule.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Mule, that is pure Spring :) And yes, you're missing the steps I'm describing above, ie load the props in a map first so you can look them up, because `context:property-placeholder` doesn't expose the properties it encapsulates.

Comment: Thanks. Worked in mule 3.7 : org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer